# ArcGIS map server not loading layer with ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: feature-layer, arcgis-rest-api, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to load the regions from here http://apps.geoportal.icimod.org/ArcGIS/rest/services/Nepal/VDC/MapServer,
but nothing is showing up.

Is there something wrong with my code?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,userscalable=no">
  <title>MapImageLayer - 4.1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.1/esri/css/main.css">
  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.1/"></script>
  <style>
    html,
    body,
    #viewDiv {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
        require([
        "esri/Map",
        "esri/views/MapView",
        "esri/layers/MapImageLayer",
        "dojo/domReady!"
      ],
      function(
        Map, MapView, MapImageLayer
      ) {
            var permitsLyr = new MapImageLayer({
      //vdc
          url: "http://apps.geoportal.icimod.org/ArcGIS/rest/services/Nepal/VDC/MapServer"
     });

    /*****************************************************************
     * Add the layer to a map
     *****************************************************************/
        var map = new Map({
          // basemap: 'streets', 
          layers: [permitsLyr]
        });

        var view = new MapView({
          container: "viewDiv",
          map: map
        });

    /*****************************************************************
     * Animate to the layer's full extent when the layer loads.
     *****************************************************************/
        permitsLyr.then(function() {
          view.goTo(permitsLyr.fullExtent);
        });
      });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
   <div id="viewDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It simply wasn't zoomed to that specified level. Its working now :)

Answer (score -1):

//add like this:

map.layers.add([permitsLyr]);

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour].  A good answer should include an explanation of how and where to use your solution, and details of what it does to solve the problem raised in the Question.